# JSON-encode several arrays

Tags: php, json

I'm using JSON_encode to send data to a js file for tracks. A user could have one or several tracks so that's where the problem lies. Not sure how to organise my array to allow for several arrays. I can't use an array within an array since all the JSON data needs to be separated preferably so there will be something like;

```
track1 {ID:110232....}
track2 {ID:21402....}
```

What I have now works fine if there is just one track.

```
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE ID = '$ID' ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $T_ID = $row['T_ID'];
    $T_url = $row['url'];
    $T_name = $row['name'];
    $T_timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
    $arr = array('T_ID' => $ID,'T_name' => $T_name, 'T_url' => $T_url, 'T_timestamp' => $T_timestamp );

    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Why does it need to be separated? It makes more sense to return one object with multiple nested objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't you use an (associative) array inside an container array like this:

```
$cont = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $T_ID = $row['T_ID'];
  $T_url = $row['url'];
  $T_name = $row['name'];
  $T_timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
  $arr = array('T_ID' => $ID,'T_name' => $T_name, 'T_url' => $T_url, 'T_timestamp' => $T_timestamp );

  $cont[] = $arr;
}

echo json_encode($cont);
```

This results in a JSON structure like this, which keeps all your tracks in separate objects:

```
[ 
  {'T_ID': 1, 'T_name': 1, ... },
  {'T_ID': 2, 'T_name': 2, ... },
  {'T_ID': 3, 'T_name': 3, ... },
  ...
]
```

<sup>As noted in the comments you should switch to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli-](http://php.net/mysqli) functions, but this doesn't matter for the problem at hand.</sup>.

Comment: Thanks very much. I know this isn't part of the problem discussed but how would i return the results of all the JSON arrays in jQuery?

Comment: @nbs189 jQuery has the [`parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function, which transforms the JSON string into a JavaScript object, which you can then use as you like.